# print a value from a select statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, variables

All I am trying to do is display the price of an item from an mysql database in an `<h1>` tag.  Nothing fancy or difficult.  I have a page that has 60 item on it, and I need to update prices on our database 2 to 3 times a year.  This would keep this page consistent with the database.

I have establish a standard mysql connect. I have defined a variable from a select statement.  Now I just need to know how to display the info. when I run this php, I get an error "Notice: Undefined variable: products in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/staging/dynamic_mixers.php on line 123"

Below is my code.

```
$products = "SELECT Base_Price FROM products Where record_number=1072;
echo "<h1>'.$products['Base_Price'].</h1>
```

Comment: care to fix the formatting of your question?

Comment: The code you've given has syntax errors. If your code was like that, you would get a different error. Can you post the exact code please? Not just lines of it, a big relevant chunk of it.

Answer (score 2):

In php, you write the query:

```
$products = "SELECT Base_Price FROM products Where record_number=1072"; //don't forget end quote
```

You make a connection to the database like this:

```
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
```

Then you send the query to be processed using the connection, like this:

```
$results = mysqli_query($connection, $products);
```

Then you need to loop through the results (even if there is only one)

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

}
```

In that loop you can access $row['Base_Price']

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['Base_Price']
}
```

Read more about it here: [PHP and MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use PHP data Objects over mysqli. Better performance and less chance of being susceptible to injection attacks.

```
// setup the query
$dbh = new PDO
(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase',
    $username,
    $password,
    array
    (
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE=>PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    )
);

$query = $dbh->Prepare('SELECT Base_Price FROM products Where record_number=? LIMIT 1');

// execute for one item
$query->execute(array(1072));
$singlePrice = $query->fetch();

// execute for the next item
$query->execute(array(1073));
$singlePrice = $query->fetch();

// execute for the third item, etc
$query->execute(array(1074));
$singlePrice = $query->fetch();
```

You can throw all of the executes in a for loop and get maximum performance since PDO is using a prepared statement.